# Using Graph API can i hide a Microsoft Teams standard channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am searching the Graph API documentation if i can hide a Microsoft Team channel, but i did not find an answer? is this a supported operation? where inside the UI we can hide the channel as follow: -

[image]

Thanks